# Writing theta on libre office

Tags: formula, libreoffice

I am typing a mathematical question by Libre Office. I've found that mathematical terms are easy to type in libre. But I got stuck while trying to type theta. There is no instruction for typing theta in `insert>object>formula`. Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in formula editor select Tools - Catalog or (Tools - Catalogue) and select the needed Symbol.

Or type %THETA or %theta in the Commands Window.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Math/Catalog

Greetings

Axel